# How do I create a game after moving to the first office?

Tags: game-dev-tycoon

I moved to the new office, and there's no option to create a new game. I've hired 2 new staff and done the management course.

Comment: You start a game just like you did it before.

Answer (score 3):

Click any where around your office and pick "Develop New Game..." option. 
Don't click your character or any of your staff members since that will open their personal menu. You can do resarch or train your staff or yourself from personal menus.